# Firebase Database: Retrieve node if child object has certain value

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Im developing an app in iOS using Firebase. Was wondering if I can fetch data in the node, if a child object has certain value?

For instance, below is my database structure:
[image]

 If i fetch data, it fetches all my data inside the `LEREDrwBDM952MpVtUE` node. However, my app solution requires me to display this node ONLY if `monitored` is false. If `monitored` is true, it will not display it.

My Code:

```
refChilds = Database.database().reference()
    let userId: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

    //observing the data changes
   refChilds.child("childId").child(userId).child("uid").queryOrdered(byChild: "monitored").queryEqual(toValue: "false").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

With the above code, Im note able to fetch anything. Is this the right way to fetch the data?

**Edit:**
Addition to my question, I was wondering how can I now update the childvalue of `monitored` from false to true? I'm having problems accessing the 2nd child node `LEREDrwBDM952MpVtUE`. My code creates a new node underneath `TGEcwrz..`

Here's my code.

```
refChild.child("childId").child(userId).updateChildValues(["monitored":monitored!])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a segment `uid` in your code that isn't in your JSON. From what I see the query should be:

```
refChilds.child("childId").child(userId).queryOrdered(byChild: "monitored").queryEqual(toValue: false).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Thanks, Frank. It worked! Just to add my silly mistake (for future users), monitored is a bool, hence it doesn't come with " ". Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I admire your solutions from various other posts too. Cheers for sorting me out too.

Comment: Woops, I had missed the booleaness, thanks for catching. Fixed in the answer too.

Comment: just one bit. Im now trying to update child value of "monitored= false" to "true". My hurdle is accessing the second child node "LEREDrwBDM952MpVtUE", which i can't. I've edited my question (bottom). Any help is much appreciated.